# Is it possible to get only rn = 1 in ROW_NUMBER without getting the rest of the rn to increase query speed?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, groupwise-maximum

So I have a query:

```
(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY itm.storeID, itm.skuID ORDER BY itm.effectiveDate DESC)) AS rn,
```

Then what I would do is use foreach in the the table then scan if rn is equal to 1, if equal then I will add to a value, so basically I sum all the rows whose rn is equal to 1...

The problem is the query for the row_number is slow (not the foreach) since it's returning 400,000+ of rows. The query is per month so I get a total of 30 rn per each partition. Then I only need the row whose rn is equal to 1...

Is there a way to do this faster? If I just wrap the query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (... rn query) t WHERE t.rn = 1
```

then I am still fetching the entire rn then only will it filter, so I'm not really making the query faster...

I also tried to put it in temp table since I am using Laravel but it doesn't work since I am using different DB_HOST for read and write...

Comment: Do not use window function, try to use aggregating subquery. Maybe it will be more effective in your particular case...

Comment: In the duplicate question there are at least 6 different methods described how to get the record with max value per group. Try the various options and see which one works the best for you.

Comment: MySQL has always had a habit of delivering a feature, but not optimizing it for a couple of major releases.  So, I don't hold out much hope for `OVER ( PARTITION ... )` in the near future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach might be fetching the MAX value of `effectiveDate` for a partition, in a separate Subquery ([Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html)). Afterwards, you can JOIN back to the main table, to get that specific row.

Defining a proper Composite index here will also help.

Try the following:

```sql
SELECT itm.* FROM itm 
JOIN (SELECT store_id, skuID, MAX(effectiveDate) AS maxDate 
      FROM itm 
      GROUP BY storeID, skuID) AS dt 
  ON dt.skuID = itm.skuID
 AND dt.storeID = itm.storeID 
 AND dt.maxDate = itm.effectiveDate
```

You will need to define a Composite Index: `(storeID, skuID, effectiveDate)` to get the best performance.

Comment: This provides a few efficient ways to do "groupwise-max":  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max